# Centos7 firefox(52.2.0 (64-bit)) Browserpush Optin message not coming

Tags: firefox, centos7, web-push

I have freshly installed Centos7 Os on my machine and it has been observed that Optin message(Allow / Disallow) of browserpush came for the https site stops working.
I have checked this with multiple websites but none of them is working which is working on chrome browser.
Anyone having any idea how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an **Extended Support Release** of Firefox and web push is currently disabled on that versions.

Comment: Actually its working on Windows Firefox whose version is 55.0.3 32bit but not working on centos firefox version

Comment: @vinitagrawal Yes... as I said, your are probably using an ESR on centos and a normal version of Firefox on Windows. The version number (55 > 52) doesn't matter: you must check if it's an ESR